# Design of simple store DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create DB of store that has books, CDs and DVDs. There are 3 categories of books: programming, cookery and e.g. spirituality. All goods have name, price, bar code. Books have pages and parametrs specialized for each category of books -- language for programming books, main ingredient for cook books, and age limit for spirituality. CDs and DVDs are devided to misic, video and Software. So, when I design DB I have a problem in connecting table: I have to take data from three different tables for one field.

```
+-----------+
| Tables    |
+-----------+
|Categories |
|Languages  |
|Main_Ingred|
|Age_Limits |
|Books      |
+-----------+

+--------------+
| Books        | 
+--------------+
|id            | 
|category_id   |
|price         | 
|bar_code      |
|pages         |
|special_param.| // Here I have to use data from 3 different tables
+--------------+
```

I think it is not right decision. Could you help me?

And I'll have the same issue for design of common table of goods.

Comment: Why not put them all in one table (books/dvds/cds); then you restrict that table so that entries that are books can only fall into your mentioned categories and cds/dvds into the others; column `pages` could stay and be nullable so it is not used for dvds/cds or you name it `length` and interpret it in code according to the type (book's length means pages, music's/video's length means seconds, software's length means MegaBytes); and I would recommend to reconsider `special_param` as it reads like some kind of tagging system this should go into a separate table referenced by a foreign key.

Comment: Do you **have** to maintain a certain `normalization form`?  If not, simplify your design.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Books, CD-s, DVD-s and whatsoever go to table products (i added the fields all of your products have)

```
+--------------+
| Products     | 
+--------------+
|id            | 
|name          |
|price         | 
|bar_code      |
+--------------+
```

then there is a table categories

```
+--------------+
| Categories   | 
+--------------+
|id            | 
|name          |
+--------------+
```

then connect the two tables (i have made many to many just in case one product goes to more categories)

```
+--------------------+
| Product2Categories | 
+--------------------+
|id                  | 
|product_id          |
|category_id         |
+--------------------+
```

last is the table for those special attributes like language, age limit, ingredients etc.

```
+--------------+
| Attributes   | 
+--------------+
|id            | 
|name          |
+--------------+
```

then you need to connect the Product with the special attribute and assign the correct value:

```
+---------------------+
| Attributes2Products | 
+---------------------+
|id                   | 
|product_id           |
|attribute_id         |
|value                |// varchar(255)
+---------------------+
```

Now this is ok but its not ideal because different attributes have different type of values, like language for programing books is a **varchar**, or age limit for spirituality is an **integer**, in the example above all the special attribute values are varchars.
If u want to optimize the database above you would need to edit the Attributes table:

```
+--------------+
| Attributes   | 
+--------------+
|id            | 
|name          |
|type          | //type of data it recives
+--------------+
```

and then create as many of Attributes2Products tables as there are datatypes you intend to use like if attribute is an integer type u save the special attribute value in table:

```
+---------------------+
| IntegerAtt2Products | 
+---------------------+
|id                   | 
|product_id           |
|attribute_id         |
|value                |// int(11)
+---------------------+
```

or if attribute is a string type

```
+---------------------+
| VarcharAtt2Products | 
+---------------------+
|id                   | 
|product_id           |
|attribute_id         |
|value                |// varchar(255)
+---------------------+
```

and so on.

Hope this helps.